# can we check if user is valid in active directory - grails 2.3.11

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi, ldap-query

As of now we are using below snippet for authentication. But we need to check without getting password from user i.e., to check only if the user is valid in active directory

```
def authenticate() {
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>()
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory")
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple")
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url)
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username)

env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pwd);
DirContext ctx

boolean loginSuccessful=false
String err=''
try {
  // Authenticate the logon user
  ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
  println "Success"
  loginSuccessful=true
} catch (NamingException ex) {
  err=ex.message
  println "${err}"
}
```

Comment: This seems more like an active-directory usage issue than grails related. There are numerous ldap plugins for grails that can provide this out-of-the-box. Please add your grails version in the intro post.

Comment: yes, thanks @TuomasValtonen its related to JNDI than grails. I'm seeing various blogs from oracle, but none to me helped finding if user already exists in active directory.

All, any help on how to dig much on LDAP functions with JNDI would be much appreciated!!

Comment: i don’t much about this area but in your position i would look for a plug-in for grails 2.3, prolly even a 1.3 plugin could work and study if that has your answer. If this ends up nowhere i would then try to approach from java angle (since 99% of the java you find is compatible with grails). This problem is solved in java with 99.999% probability. Just changing the question tag from grails to java could yield a lot of more answers